# "The selected node does not have a form ancestor"

Tags: php, behat, gherkin, mink

I'm testing my PHP / bootstrap application with Behat + Mink. I'm currently trying to use variables to grab from a field with a Scenario Outline.

The website looks like this
[image]

My code looks like this 
**in feature file**
    Feature: Stock Portfolio
        In order to see what stocks are owned
        As a user
        I want to display my portfolio

```
    Scenario: User Is On Home Page
        Given that I am logged in
        When print current URL
        Then I should see "Portfolio"


    Scenario Outline: User Buys Stock
        Given that I am logged in
        And I own <start> "AAPL" stocks
        When I fill in "ticker" with "AAPL"
        And I sell <sell> stock
        Then I should own <finish> "AAPL" stocks

        Examples:
            | start | sell | finish |
            |  13   |  5   |  8     |
            |  10   |  3   |  7     |
```

**in php file**

```
 /**
     * @Then /^I should own (.*) "([^"]*)" stocks$/
     */
    public function iShouldOwnStocks($start, $arg1)
    {
        $this->assertSession()->fieldValueEquals($arg1, $start);
    }



    /**
     * @Given /^I sell (.*) stock$/
     */
    public function iSellStock($sell)

    {
        $this->fillField("quantity", $sell);
    }

    /**
     * @Given /^I own (.*) "([^"]*)" stocks$/
     */
    public function iOwnStocks($start, $arg1)
    {
        $this->assertSession()->fieldValueEquals($arg1, $start);

    }
```

The error I keep getting is:

[image: Error]

I'm not quite sure what's going on here - help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**First**, about the regex:

Do not use `(.*)` unless it is at the end of a step definition, as a helpful hint for you, or other developers bug fixing later on. This regex literally means, accept any character except a new line.

Instead, use `([0-9]+)`, which will only accept numbers, or `([\d]+)`, which again, will only accept numbers, and will only accept them if there is 1 or more.

**Secondly**, about the regex:

Try to also encapsulate the number using double quotes, `"([0-9]+)"` or `"([\d]+)"`, which should do the same as above, but makes it slightly more clear, by only allowing numbers in quotes.

**Penultimately**, about the regex

If you are still having trouble with the digits, because of a decimal place, use this:

`"([\d])*\.?([\d]){0,2}"`

Which will capture any amount of numbers before, an optional decimal place, and up to two numbers after.

**Lastly**, about duplication of functions

You assert the same thing twice in two separate step definitions.
Personally, I would change the

```
/**
 * @Then /^I should own (.*) "([^"]*)" stocks$/
 */
public function iShouldOwnStocks($start, $arg1)
{
    $this->assertSession()->fieldValueEquals($arg1, $start);
}
```

function to

```
/**
 * @Then /^I (?:|should )own "([0-9]+)" "([^"]*)" stocks$/
 */
public function iShouldOwnStocks($start, $arg1)
{
    $this->assertSession()->fieldValueEquals($arg1, $start);
}
```

Which will make the "should" optional, meaning no duplication of the same assertion needed, making your context less messy.

Basically, you will no longer need this:

```
/**
 * @Given /^I own (.*) "([^"]*)" stocks$/
 */
public function iOwnStocks($start, $arg1)
{
    $this->assertSession()->fieldValueEquals($arg1, $start);

}
```

If there is still a problem after the regex fixes I have suggested, leave a comment, and I will attempt to answer it in a new paragraph.

Comment: Super helpful. Thank you! Apologies - I thought my reply went through